# How to access a individual view in _layout.cshtml in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, layout

In MVC how to access an individual view in _layout.cshtml?

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()  
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ContactUs()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Header()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

When I writeclick on adding a view(header and contactus) then select this view see below.
ContactUs.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ContactUs";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
}

<h2>ContactUs</h2>

@section ContactUs{
    <h1>this is contact view</h1>
}
```

Header.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Header";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Header</h2>

@section Header{
    <h1>this is header view</h1>
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderSection("Header")   //Additional information: Section not defined: "Header".
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("ContactUs") //Additional information: Section not defined: "ContactUs".
        <footer>
            <p>2016@CopyRightsReserved</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

//Additional information: Section not defined: "Header". get an error runtime

what I m doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of RenderSection is wrong. RenderSection is used to render the section of HTML snippet defined in your your view. You cannot use RenderSection to call controller action. [Read here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/asp-net-mvc-5-renderbody-renderpage-and-rendersection-with-example.php).

Alternatively you can use Html.RenderAction to render the Controller Action. But, you need to return PartialView result from the action. [Read Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-Asp-Net-mvc/).

Comment: when I declare header function in index.cshtml then render section work but when I create an individual view through a controller then render section not work??

Comment: Yes that's correct RenderSection's scope is only to render the sections defined in view file. You can use Html.RenderAction or simply Html.Partial to render you header

Comment: ```@Html.Action and @{Html.RenderAction("");}``` both functions are only work with partial view i m wrong or not??

Comment: As I see from your code what you really need is partial view only.

Answer (score 0):

Just update you _Layout.cshtml to pass additional parameter to RenderSection:

```
@RenderSection("Header", false)
```

That way, when the page doesn't have a section specified it will not throw an exception.

---

Btw, it looks like you might be looking for rendering a partial view. In this case your Header view would need to be updated to smth simple:

```
<h2>Header</h2>
```

And in _Layout.cshtml you would just need to call

```
@Html.Partial("Header")
```